# Maximize area of intersecting triangle and square with constraints

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry

There is this [nice problem on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282195/maximum-area-of-the-intersection-of-a-parallelogram-and-a-triangle) to find a maximum intersection area of a square and a triangle with a constraint that they both have unit areas.

I tried to solve it with a help of Mathematica as follows

```
iarea[a_, rot_, d_] := Module[{sqr, trg, pA, h, pD, pC},
 (*define a unit square*)
 sqr = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}];
 (*assuming the 1st triangle vertex is at origin, 
  and the 2nd in the direction rot and distance a *)
 pA = a {Cos[rot], Sin[rot]};
 (*move distance h in the perpendicular direction to find the 3rd vertex*)
 h = 2/a;
 pD = d {Cos[rot], Sin[rot]};
 pC = pD + h {Cos[rot + \[Pi]/2], Sin[rot + \[Pi]/2]};
 trg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, pA, pC}];
 (* compute intersection and its area*)
 Area[RegionIntersection[{sqr, trg}]]
]
```

I am trying to beat this value

```
iarea[Sqrt[2], 0.0, 0]
(*0.828427*)
```

with the help of `NMaximise` as follows

```
NMaximize[{iarea[xa, xr, xd],xa < 3 && xd <= xa && xa > 0 && xd > 0 && xr > 0 && xr < \[Pi]/2}, {xa, xr, xd}]
```

where I put some constraints on the angle `rot`, the length of one side `a`, and the `d`. However, the run takes too long, I was not patient enough to wait. Can I hope for a solution in this way? Is there a better/faster way?

Comment: iarea[Sqrt[2], 0.0, 0] returns RegionIntersection::reg: {Polygon[{{0,0},{0,1},{1,1},{1,0}}],Polygon[{{0,0},{1.41421,0.},{8.65956*10^-17,1.41421}}]} is not a correctly specified region. and the input for me in version 11.2.0.0.

Comment: @user64494 Strange, I am on MA 11.0.1.0 and on a fresh kernel there is no problem

Comment: `Area[RegionIntersection[sqr, trg]]` worked both version 11.1 and 11.2.

Comment: In 10.4 `Area[RegionIntersection[sqr, trg]]` gets it right about 50% of the time. For the rest is gets the intersection wrong -- by missing out vertices or getting their order in `Polygon`.

Comment: @aardvark2012 is it a bug in MA10.4 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do better that `2(Sqrt[2] - 1)`, but here's a way to get `NMaximize` working on the problem. I'm not sure exactly what it is about your approach that makes it take so long (I ran out of patience, too), but it could be that `RegionIntersection` is causing trouble. You could try plotting

```
Plot3D[iarea[a, 0, d], {a, d} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[0 < d < a < 3, {a, d}]]
```

and see if it looks anything like mine:

[image]

It's no surprise that a surface like that takes a long time to navigate! The reason for this (in my case) is that `RegionIntersection[square, triangle]` does things like this:

```
RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0.5, 2}}]]

(* Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0.25, 1}, {0.75, 1.}}] *)
```

Clearly the `Polygon` of the intersection is a little messed up, and is missing the point `{1, 0}`. (Using exact numbers, ie `0.5 -> 1/2` in `triangle`, removes the problem in this case). So I've had to include my own intersection function. Pretty much all the code in this answer is constructing a working `RegionIntersection` function, so let me get that out of the way now.

**Region Intersections**

The first function, `lineintersection`, tests to see if the lines between two pairs of vertices intersect, and if so, where. The second, `triangleintersection` calculates all the vertices of the intersection and returns the intersection `Polygon`. Note that *the arguments for this function are set up specifically for this maximization problem*, and certainly can't be used in a more general setting without substantial rewriting. Specifically, it calculates intersection of the square `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]` with a triangle with vertices `{{x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 2/(y - x)}}` (I'll explain why those vertices below):

```
lineintersection[{x : {x1_, x2_}, y : {y1_, y2_}}, {u : {u1_, u2_}, v : {v1_, v2_}}] := 
 Module[{denom = (u2 - v2) (x1 - y1) - (u1 - v1) (x2 - y2)},
  If[denom == 0, Nothing,
   With[{a = (-v2 x1 + u2 (-v1 + x1) + u1 (v2 - x2) + v1 x2)/denom, 
     b = -(-x2 y1 + u2 (-x1 + y1) + u1 (x2 - y2) + x1 y2)/denom},
    If[0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1,
     x + a (y - x)(* or u+b(v-u)*), Nothing]
    ]
   ]
  ]

triangleintersection[x1_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{x = {x1, 0}, y = {y1, 0}, z = {z1, 2/(y1 - x1)}, allpoints},
  allpoints = DeleteDuplicates[Join[
     (* Find all points where a square edge intersects a triangle edge *)
     lineintersection @@@ Tuples[{Subsets[{x, y, z}, {2}], 
       {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}}}],
     (* Include vertices of the square that lie inside the triangle, and vice versa *)
     Join[
      Pick[#, RegionMember[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], #]] &@{x, y, z},
      Pick[#, RegionMember[Triangle[{x, y, z}], #]] &@{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]],
    Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-10 &];
  Polygon[SortBy[allpoints, ArcTan @@ (# - Mean[allpoints]) &]]
 ]
```

Moving on to the actual question...

**Problem setup**

I've taken the liberty of changing the space of triangles we're searching over.Given a square with vertices `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}`, I'm going to assume (for the moment) that:

*The triangle has one (or possibly two) edge(s) lying along an edge of the square.*

Without loss of generality, then, we can assume that the first two vertices are `{x, 0}` and `{y, 0}`, with `y > x`. Then the third vertex is `{z, 2/(y - x)}`. So it's still a 3D space to search over, as in your `iarea`, but contains the solution in the thread you linked to plus other maximal solutions, too.

You can explore this space by hand with

```
Manipulate[
 intersection = triangleintersection[x, y, z];
 Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.32, 0.5, 0.68]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
    EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.76, 0.73, 0.87]], Triangle[{{x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 2/(y - x)}}], 
    EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.94, 0.28, 0.18]], intersection, 
    PointSize[Large], Point[intersection[[1]]]}], 
  PlotLabel -> "Area = " <> ToString@Area@intersection],
 {{x, 1/2 - Sqrt[2]/2}, -1, 0.5}, {{y, 1/2 + Sqrt[2]/2}, 0.5, 2}, {{z, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

As a comparison to the surface I plotted above, a portion of the surface to be searched with a working intersection function looks like this:

```
Plot3D[Area@triangleintersection[x, y, 0.3], {x, -1, 0.4}, {y, 0.6, 2}]
```

[image]

After all this, finding the maximum area of the intersection is pretty straightforward. Define an `area` function using `triangleintersection`:

```
area[x1_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ] := 
  With[{int = triangleintersection[x1, y1, z1]}, 
    If[Length[int[[1]]] < 3, 0, Area@int]
  ]
```

and then maximize:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  sol = NMaximize[{area[x, y, z], 
    -1. <= x < 0.25 && 0.75 <= y <= 2. && 0 <= z <= 1}, 
  {x, y, z}]
]

(* {2.21181, {0.828427, {x -> -0.233978, y -> 1.18024, z -> 0.564872}}} *)
```

Which is fairly speedy and successfully finds a triangle with an intersection area of `2 (Sqrt[2] - 1)`.

```
triangle = Triangle[{{x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 2/(y - x)}} /. sol[[2]]];
intersection = triangleintersection[x, y, z] /. sol[[2]];
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.32, 0.5, 0.68]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
 EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.76, 0.73, 0.87]], triangle, 
 EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.94, 0.28, 0.18]], intersection, 
   PointSize[Large], Point[intersection[[1]]]}], 
 PlotLabel -> "Area = " <> ToString@Area@intersection]
```

[image]

**Generalising to 5D**

We can generalising to the full 5D subspace of triangles with unit with a straightforward adaptation of the area function from above. I'm going to add two more variables: a "displacement", `d`, which moves the `xy`-line off the `x`-axis, and a rotation, `\[Theta]`, about the origin. Specifically, the vertices of the triangle are defined as

$$
   x = R_\theta.(x_1, d), \quad y = R_\theta.(y_1, d) \quad \text{and} \quad z = R_\theta.\left(z_1, \frac{2}{y_1 - x_1} + d\right)
$$

The only differences with the 3D functions I used earlier are in the function arguments and the `Module` definitions. So to save screen ink, just replace the function and `Module` lines in the definition of `triangleintersection` with:

```
triangleintersection5[x1_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, 
  d_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ] := Module[{
   x = RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{x1, d}, 
   y = RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{y1, d}, 
   z = RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{z1, 2/(y1 - x1) + d}, 
   allpoints},
```

and define

```
area5[x1_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{int = triangleintersection5[x1, y1, z1, d, \[Theta]]}, 
  If[Length[int[[1]]] < 3, 0, Area@int]
 ]
```

As before, you can explore this space with:

```
Manipulate[
 triangle = Triangle[RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].# & /@ {{x, d}, {y, d}, {z, 2/(y - x) + d}}];
 intersection = triangleintersection5[x, y, z, d, \[Theta]];
 Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.32, 0.5, 0.68]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
  EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.76, 0.73, 0.87]], triangle, 
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.94, 0.28, 0.18]], inersection, 
  PointSize[Medium], Point[intersection[[1]]]}], 
 PlotLabel -> ToString@Area@intersection],
 {{x, 1/2 - Sqrt[2]/2}, -1, 0.5}, {{y, 1/2 + Sqrt[2]/2}, 0.5, 2}, 
 {{z, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{d, -0.2}, -1, 1}, {{\[Theta], Pi/4}, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Finding a maximal triangle:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol = NMaximize[{area5[x, y, z, d, \[Theta]], -1. <= x < 0.25 && 
     0.75 <= y <= 2 && 0 <= z <= 1 && -1 <= d <= 1 && 
     -Pi/2 <= \[Theta] <= Pi/2}, {x, y, z, d, \[Theta]}]
]

(* {10.0285, {0.828427, {x -> -0.00236893, y -> 1.41184, z -> 0.00572204,
d -> -5.14455*10^-7, \[Theta] -> 1.23502*10^-6}}} *)

triangle = Triangle[{RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{x, d}, 
     RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{y, d}, 
     RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{z, 2/(y - x) + d}} /. sol[[2]]];
intersection = triangleintersection5[x, y, z, d, \[Theta]] /. sol[[2]];
Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.32, 0.5, 0.68]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
 EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.76, 0.73, 0.87]], triangle, 
 EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.94, 0.28, 0.18]], intersection, 
 PointSize[Medium], Point[intersection[[1]]]}], 
 PlotLabel -> "Area = " <> ToString@Area@intersection]
```

[image]

Which gives the same area as before, and was in fact  in the earlier search space.

Comment: So with your approach you can find a family of solutions with the same maximal area. As TimothyBudd writes on mathoverflow: "If you move the tip as well as the base in such a way that the intersections with the vertical sides are unchanged, then the overlapping area does not change." Interesting!